# Desktop settings (background and applets) disappear in Kubuntu 20.1

Tags: kubuntu, 20.10, settings, desktop-background

I just installed Kubuntu 20.1 but every time I log in the desktop background disappears along with any applet that I set up earlier.

Every time I restart or turn off my laptop I get a black desktop background. The only thing that stays are the linked access icons of some software I put on the desktop.

I searched and found that changing the permissions of the usr/share/wallpapers folder was a solution, but it hasn't worked for me. I tried adding my pictures folder in the desktop settings and deleting the default folders (usr/wallpapers/ and usr/plasma/wallpapers) from the list of sources, so my images would load from home/myuser/pictures and select an image from that folder, but when I restart the system the desktop is black and when I check the settings the default folders are there again, My pictures folder is out of the list, a default image is selected (usually he first one) and the desktop is black. JUst when I click in another image, the background changes.

What can I do? I want my desktop settings saved and appear every time I log in.

I'll appreciate any help on this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: Well I couldn't find help anywhere, I tried some solutions that I found for this problem but they did not worked for me, maybe because were for older versions. So I reinstalled Kubuntu and repeated everything I did checking on every step (updating the system, installing drivers, installing software, changing some devices setup, etc) and found the cause that also works for Kubuntu 20.04, which I also tested and got the same problem. So I will post it here in case someone else has the same issue.

The problem was caused by a global theme. After downloading and installing the theme  "sweet KDE" my desktop turned black and every setting on the desktop stop being saved. I also installed and applied other 4 themes to check if they triggered the issue, and they didn't.

The "sweet KDE" theme also caused another issue in KUBUNTU 20.04 (NOT in 20.10): after installing the theme I could not restart, poweroff, or close session because the "KDE greeting"(I don't remember the full name of the app) froze leaving a blur screen with no options, so the only way to poweroff or restart was using the terminal.

**THE SOLUTION:** ***uninstall the theme***. That's it. After uninstalling the theme all the problems went away and everything is working as it should again :)

The only annoying thing is that although I uninstalled the theme I still see it in the list of installed themes.

I hope this helps anyone that crosses with this kind of issue.

Comment: The same happened to me with the default Breeze Dark theme. Had to reset the theme by choosing "use desktop layout from theme", and then reconfigure my destop. This is kubuntu 20.04, this happened after the last updated, not sure which package is responsible,.